# Can't compose a regex for parsing date and time

Tags: php

I'm trying to make regex for

`|Thu Aug 28 16:08:44`

into

```
$form = array ('/[|A-Za-z ]+/','/[0-3][0-9 ]/','([0-9]+):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])/');
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Just tell me why regex for date you can use direct date function instead.

Comment: *$form = array ('/[|A-Za-z ]+/','/[0-3][0-9 ]/','([0-9]+):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])/');* what should this be? where have you read that an array has something equal with regex? btw you can simply use strtotime() instead of regex or other date functions

Comment: Nothing here makes sense. What is the array for?!

Comment: I want to replace |Thu Aug 28 16:08:44 or other date and time with space character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you're using the array, but here is a regex that will match your string...

```
\|([A-Z]|[a-z])+ ([A-Z]|[a-z])+ ([0-3]?[0-9]) [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
```

The question mark in the middle is in case your date < 10 (e.g. `|Thu Aug 8 16:44:24` - if it'll always have a leading zero then that question mark is not required. It also assumes that the hour will always have 2 digits, (implied by your 24 hour clock) - if not put a question mark after `[0-2]`